# WPA2 MIC 128bits value VS HMAC SHA1 output 160bits

Tags: wifi, wpa2

I understand that under WPA2, if the MIC value is equal to the HMAC SHA1 function, that means the password from dictionary attack works.

However, after deriving the MIC value from Wireshark, which is 128 bits and the HMAC SHA1 function which takes in 128 bit KCK along with 802.1x packet would output 160 bits.

How then can I compare the 128 bits MIC to HMAC SHA1 output 160 bits? Is there anything i am missing out?